# Issue saving SQL query results in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

My query results look like this in SQL Server. EmpBarr has string with multiple values that must be double quoted and comma delimited.

```
id      EmpBarr
6928108 "ELL","LII","LLL"
```

When I copy the results to the excel worksheet (text formatted cells) , I lose the quotes from the `ELL` in EmpBarr column converting it to `ELL,"LII","LLL"`

Is there any work around for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it. I do not need quotes around each concatenated value ; all I need is

```
id,EmpBarr
6928108,"ELL,LII,LLL"
```

Modified the script to handle it.